# webkit customised scroll bar buttons are missing in mac

Tags: css, html, macos, webkit

I have customised my scroll bar using css and using custom buttons at the top and bottom of scroll bar. the css is as below

```
<style type="text/css">
        ::-webkit-scrollbar {   
        width: 14px;
        background: #373737;
        border:1px solid #1A1A1A;    
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb 
        {
        background:rgba(70,70,70,0.85);
        border:1px solid #060606;
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
        background: #000;
        }
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement {
        background-image: url(images/webkit_scrollUp.png);
        border:1px solid #060606;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;       
        }
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment {
        background-image: url(images/webkit_scrollDown.png);
        border:1px solid #060606;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;      
        }
    </style>
```

It is working fine in chrome in windows 7.
But when I tested it in macbook pro, in chrome the scroll is customised, it is fine. but the scroll buttons at the top and bottom of scroll is missing.
What would be the reason and is there any fixes for that

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/zetqR/1/  the jsfiddle is here

Comment: dont know how to create it

Comment: Put your existing code into JSfiddle and give us the link. We can then play with the code ourselves. Don't forget to provide the images too.

Comment: Macs don't have scroll bar buttons. Thats probably the reason they aren't there.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zetqR/1/